# React spread list of attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have,

```
<RadioContainer
    nonRepeating="val"
    repeating1={this.props.radioGroupAttributes.getIn([variable, 'visibility'])}
    repeating2={this.props.radioGroupAttributes.getIn([variable, 'type'])}
    repeating3={this.props.allVisible}
    repeating4="address"
    nonRepeating="xyz"
/>
```

Only the argument `variable` in *repeating attributes 1,2* differs among all `RadioContainer` Components that I have used several times in my code.

I want,

```
<RadioContainer
    nonRepeating="val"
    foo(variable) //should return desired format
    nonRepeating="xyz"
/>
```

The `foo(variable)` should expand or spread to make the above block of code look like the one above it.

`RadioContainer` Component is used several times and I don't want to repeat the repeating attributes every time I write `RadioContainer` Component. Instead call a function passing it variable and it should return desired format.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{...foo(variable)} should do the trick.

```
<RadioContainer
    nonRepeating="val"
    nonRepeating="xyz"
    {...foo(variable)}
/>
```

foo(variable) should return

```
{
   repeating1 :this.props.radioGroupAttributes.getIn([variable, 'visibility']), 
   repeating2: this.props.radioGroupAttributes.getIn([variable, 'type']),
   repeating3: this.props.allVisible
}
```